# Is a for-loop the right way of removing an object from an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

So, I'm trying to remove an object from an ArrayList. When I do it and print the ArrayList again, the object is still there.

```
     else if (cmd==4){
        System.out.println("Enter the product name: ");
        String nameToRemove = input.next();
        for (Product x : inventoryList){
           if (nameToRemove == x.getName()){
              inventoryList.remove(x);
           }
        }
     }
```

Why won't the remove() method do anything when I implement it?

Comment: You are comparing strings with == instead of equals()

Comment: Apart from String comparison, use iterator to perform remove operation to avoid concurrentmodifcationexception.

Comment: see `ArrayList.removeIf()` method

Comment: @bayou.io Ooooh that's shiny! Happy to see that Java is getting more Haskellian.

Comment: @TuttiFruttiJacuzzi - no...... Java will never be any where near haskel in type system:) ever!